# c++ validate range of characters

Tags: c++, validation

I'm writing a function that is passed a character as the first argument and an integer as the second.  I need to validate both simultaneously.  Specifically, the character must be between A and J (including A and J), and the integer must be between 1 and 10 (including 1 and 10).

The line I wrote is:

```
if (toupper(row) < 'A' || toupper(row) > 'J' || col < 1 || col > 10)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{ ... rest of function ... }
```

but this is not working correctly.  In my book I read that you could perform comparisons with characters because they really are just integers themselves, but I can't figure out why ths won't work.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit to address some comments**

0 is the number we're supposed to return if the input is not valid.

This line of code is part of a project that is being graded by a "test driver" that my teacher wrote.  The test driver is reporting that my function is not returning the correct result when the input is invalid (character that is not between A or J, or a number that is lower than 1 or greater than 10).

I structured my code so that if the statement above is **true**, then it returns the code we were supposed to return, otherwise it proceeds with the rest of the function...  So I can't figure out why his test driver is telling me that I'm not returning the code when given invalid input.  The other problem is he doesn't let us see what the test driver is sending to our function, so I have no way of trouble shooting this.

Comment: Your logic is inverted, do a barrel roll!

Comment: THe code looks like it correctly detects invalid characters.  Why do you say it's not working correctly?

Comment: You said "...this is not working correctly."  What do you intend it to do, and what is it doing?

Comment: "not working correctly" is **never** a good diagnoses. Please **edit** your post by adding the expected behavior and the wrong one.

Comment: Put this function here, all of it.

Comment: What input is failing?

Comment: I don't know, my teacher's test driver says it passed what should be invalid input, but my function did not report it as invalid.  The input should be reported as invalid if it's not A-J or 1-10.

Comment: Maybe my updated answer will help;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't use toupper. Why?

Because maybe your professor use invalid input like:

```
a, 5
```

and you shouldn't allow lower cases to pass your test.

So in the end your if statement:

```
 if ((row >= 'A' && row <= 'J') && (col > 0 && col < 11))
```

Comment: That's exactly the same test, but inverted. Since the OP didn't say what the body of the `if ` does you have no way to tell if that helps.

Comment: Yes,you're right,then after few updates of question I think I found an answer.

Comment: This works.  I flipped the statement around so the rest of my function is under the true branch using this.  Also we were told (verbally) that case doesn't matter, which is why I used toupper(), but apparently his test driver is looking for upper case only.  I didn't think to NOT use toupper() because we were specifically told that case doesn't matter...  Hence my frustration trying to figure this out.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From your post it is not clear what does not work. You wrote if statement without any compound statement. So what is the criterion that something is wrong?!

For example you could write

```
if (toupper(row) < 'A' || toupper(row) > 'J' || col < 1 || col > 10) return false;
```

Take into account that negation of expression

```
if ((toupper(row) >= 'A' && toupper(row) <= 'J') && (col > 0 && col < 11) )
```

as it is written by **@Ardel** is equivalent to

```
if ( !( ( toupper(row) >= 'A' && toupper(row) <= 'J') && (col > 0 && col < 11 ) ) )
```

that in turn is equivalent to

```
if ( !( toupper(row) >= 'A' && toupper(row) <= 'J') || !(col > 0 && col < 11 ) ) )
```

that is equivalent to

```
if ( !( toupper(row) >= 'A' ) || !( toupper(row) <= 'J') || !(col > 0 ) || !( col < 11 ) )
```

that is equivalent to

```
if ( toupper(row) < 'A' || toupper(row) > 'J' || col <= 0 ) || col >= 11 )
```

that is at last equivalent to

```
if (toupper(row) < 'A' || toupper(row) > 'J' || col < 1 || col > 10) return false;
```

That is your original expression.

**So there is no any sense in your post and in the answer of @Ardel.**

So I do not understand for example why the answer of @Ardel was uo voted. Maybe it was up voted by whose who is unable to do such conversions as the negation of boolean expressions?:)

I can suppose (moreover after thinking about I am sure) that you should not apply function toupper to the character. For example

```
if ( row < 'A' || row > 'J' || col < 1 || col > 10) return 0;
```

The other problem is that you did not say what the function shall do if this condition will be passed successfuly. Maybe inside the function body you should reassign row the following way

```
row -= 'A';
```

that to use it as integer value between 1 and 10 inclusively.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I added the rest of the if statement.  If the input is invalid, the function should return 0, otherwise proceed with the rest of the function.

Comment: @Sabien In your description there is nothing said that the character has to be converted to upper case.